# visual studio code-should I install python in virtual environment in the folder of my project?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I have set up my virtual environment in a project folder on my desktop, I also used pip install to install django 2.2 in this project folder on my desktop. I have python installed, but it is in another folder elsewhere on my computer, do I need to install python in the same project folder on my desktop? I am getting messages in virtual studio, which say, "visual studio code, workspace contains pipfile but 'pipenv' was not found". Also when  try to use pip install to install python into the project folder on my desktop I get an error message in terminal(I am using a mac) which says,

```
pip install python3.8
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3.8 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3.8
```

I'm also getting error messages which say:

```
visual studio code no python interpreter is selected
```

&

```
there is no pip installer available in the selected environment
```

So overall, do I need to install python in the project folder and if so, how do I do this? Do i need to install the python interpreter as well? I have had a problem with bash wherein  have to type:

PATH=/Users/aleong/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH

to create my virtual environment, I'm not sure if this is why python won't install, however  I did type this into my terminal initially..

plz help, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well, from the error message you get about Pipfile, it means that you need to install [pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/) which is by itself a virtual environment. After installing it go to your project and type this `pipenv shell` this should activate your virtual env and then type this `pipenv install` this should install all dependencies from Pipfile.

Comment: if I type "brew install pipenv" as the directions say on "https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/" to install pipenv, I get the following error message: "bash: brew: command not found". According to "https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/" -i already have pip installed as they say it was installed with "Python 3 >=3.4" however it is in another folder on my computer, not in the project folder I am currently working in, does this mean I should install python in the project folder I'm working in?

Comment: ok,  I have been able to install and activate the virtual environment by typing: "pip install pipenv". I then cd into my project folder, typed "which python3"-it gave me a file path, i then used this file path for the command: "pipenv --python /Users/myHomePage/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3". It created a virtual env for this project. Then I typed "pipenv shell" which activated the virtual environment. However, on the bottom left corner of visual studio, if I click on python, where I can "enter interpreter path" it brings up 2 versions of python in other locations on my hd,not in my project folder

Comment: is it ok to use these versions of python which are located  outside the project folder or do i install python in the project folder I'm working in?

Comment: I believe I solved this question so this can b closed